# Using regular expression (String + number) in Scala

Tags: java, regex, scala

I am using regression expression to find the patterns such as:

```
"Today USER ID: 123556 cancelled"
"January USER ID: 236477 renewed"
"February USER ID: 645689 dispute"
```

Basically I am looking for the string contains "USER ID: " + number. I am using the following code, but it couldn't match anything. Could anyone please give some suggestions?

```
if (myString.matches("USER ID: ([0-9]+)")) {
      println(a)
}
```

Comment: string.matches("^.*USER ID: ([0-9]+).*$") will match what you have edited the question to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should just be:

```
if (myString.matches("^USER ID: ([0-9]+)$")) {
```

without the slashes in the regex string and with a space after USER ID:

just tested and it worked for me as follows:

```
String string =  "USER ID: 12345";
if(string.matches("^USER ID: ([0-9]+)$")){
     System.out.println("matches");
}
```

There are lots of good "regex cheatsheets" out there. You can find one such here:
http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: Just noticed that I have char before and after my pattern, e.g. "January USER ID: 12345 cancelled". Then it doesn't seem to work ... is there any additional modification required? Thanks!

Comment: string.matches("^.*USER ID: ([0-9]+).*$") will match what you have edited the question to

Answer (score 1):

```
^USER ID: ([0-9]+)$

        ^^
```

You are missing this `space`.

Comment: Hi, I just added the space, using "/^USER ID: ([0-9]+)$/"  still doesn't work

Comment: @Edamame use `^USER ID: ([0-9]+)$`, not `/^USER ID: ([0-9]+)$/`

Comment: Thanks. Just noticed that I have char before and after my pattern, e.g. "January USER ID: 12345 cancelled". So I modified it to ".USER ID: ([0-9]+)." But the . char doesn't seem to work right, am I missing anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Scala (following tag in question), define this regex

```
val re = "USER ID:\\s+\\d+".r
```

where we allow for several spaces before the sequence of digits; thus for

```
val a = "Today USER ID: 123556 cancelled"

re.findFirstIn(a)
Option[String] = Some(USER ID: 123556)
```

delivers `Some[String]` value if the pattern was found, `None` otherwise.

To respond whether the pattern was found, consider

```
re.findFirstIn(a).isDefined
res: Boolean: true
```